# removing the js script from html page

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

```html
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>

<head>
  <title>disturbed</title>

  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      // create the canvas
      var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
        c = canvas.getContext("2d");
      var particles = {};
      var particleIndex = 0;
      var particleNum = 15;

      // set canvas size
      canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
      canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

      // add canvas to body
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);

      // style the canvas
      c.fillStyle = "black";
      c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      function Particle() {
        this.x = canvas.width / 2;
        this.y = canvas.height / 2;
        this.vx = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
        this.vy = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
        this.gravity = 0.3;
        particleIndex++;
        particles[particleIndex] = this;
        this.id = particleIndex;
        this.life = 0;


        this.maxLife = Math.random() * 30 + 60;


        this.color = "hsla(" + parseInt(Math.random() * 360, 10) + ",90%,60%,0.5";
      }

      Particle.prototype.draw = function() {
        this.x += this.vx;
        this.y += this.vy;


        if (Math.random() < 0.1) {
          this.vx = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
          this.vy = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
        }

        this.life++;
        if (this.life >= this.maxLife) {
          delete particles[this.id];
        }

        c.fillStyle = this.color;
        //c.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 5, 10);
        c.beginPath();
        c.arc(this.x, this.y, 2.5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        c.fill();
      };

      setInterval(function() {
        //normal setting before drawing over canvas w/ black background
        c.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
        c.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)";
        c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        for (var i = 0; i < particleNum; i++) {
          new Particle();
        }

        // c.globalCompositeOperation = "darken";

        for (var i in particles) {
          particles[i].draw();
        }
      }, 30);
    };
  </script>


</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

The code below is all correct but its just two densed i want to make it easier and not to populated . what i want to do is make the script that i have into a separate file like "anything.js" so that i can load it into my html main file by just calling out the main functions like particle() in ,window.onload = function() which will be on the main page .
The reason is because i want to add this script to many html pages and i dont want to copy all of the lengthy script in to my code again and again .
Please answer this , it would be really helful.

Comment: `<script src="anything.js"></script>`

Comment: but i want the window.onload = function() {
} to exist on my main html files and in it i want to call the functions like particle(); animate() etc.

Comment: So include that in anything.js.

Comment: @FasihSajid so what prevents you from having onload in it?

Comment: i want something like this to work, this is just a basic idea of how i want it to look like 


<script    src="anything.js"></script>
    <script>
    MAX_DEPTH = 32;
 
    var canvas, ctx;
    var stars = new Array(500);
 
    window.onload = function() {
      canvas = document.getElementById("tutorial");
      if( canvas && canvas.getContext ) {
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        particle();
        setInterval();
       }
    }
 
  
  </script>

Comment: ...yes, that sort of thing should work; what goes wrong when you try it?    Is it possible your problem is that you're overwriting the window.onload handler as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751362/window-onload-in-external-script-gets-ignored-in-javascript)?

Comment: Well you really should rethink the code and not use global variables to initialize it. You really should make a function that you call and send it the details and have it set the onload

Comment: @DanielBeck i know this should work but i dont now how to proceed with this.

Comment: What does that mean? what goes wrong when you try it?  It's not clear what you're asking for at this point.

Comment: 1)i want two files 1)Disturbed.html 2)anything.js

2)in my html file i want 2 script tags one that will contain <script src"anything.js> and another which will contain the windows.onload function () which will call the rest of the functions particle(), set interval() etc etc .
but i don't know how to proceed and do the above mentioned steps

Answer (score 2):

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>

<head>
  <title>disturbed</title>   
</head>

<body>

<script src="toto.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        Particle();
    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

toto.js :

```
//create the canvas
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
c = canvas.getContext("2d");
var particles = {};
var particleIndex = 0;
var particleNum = 15;

// set canvas size
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

// add canvas to body
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// style the canvas
c.fillStyle = "black";
c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

function Particle() {
this.x = canvas.width / 2;
this.y = canvas.height / 2;
this.vx = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
this.vy = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
this.gravity = 0.3;
particleIndex++;
particles[particleIndex] = this;
this.id = particleIndex;
this.life = 0;


this.maxLife = Math.random() * 30 + 60;


this.color = "hsla(" + parseInt(Math.random() * 360, 10) + ",90%,60%,0.5";
}

Particle.prototype.draw = function() {
this.x += this.vx;
this.y += this.vy;


if (Math.random() < 0.1) {
    this.vx = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
    this.vy = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
}

this.life++;
if (this.life >= this.maxLife) {
    delete particles[this.id];
}

c.fillStyle = this.color;
//c.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 5, 10);
c.beginPath();
c.arc(this.x, this.y, 2.5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
c.fill();
};

setInterval(function() {
//normal setting before drawing over canvas w/ black background
c.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
c.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)";
c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
for (var i = 0; i < particleNum; i++) {
    new Particle();
}

// c.globalCompositeOperation = "darken";

for (var i in particles) {
    particles[i].draw();
}
}, 30);
```

Comment: nope it is still not  working can you attach a code snippet ?

Comment: Indeed, you need to load the scripts before the closing tag of your body. I'll edit my previous answer. There are bugs in the js file, but they seem unrelated to your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I see you have a scope issue.

Variables are passed from script to script. However, in your case, you declare `Particle` inside `window.onload` so it only gets defined inside it and you can't use it elsewhere.

The right way to export your script into a separate file would be to declare `Particle` in the scope of the whole script, as in:

```
// anything.js
function Particle() {
    ...
}
```

Note that you'd need a bit of rewriting, since I can see that you use variables like `canvas` (which are only defined in the scope of `window.onload`) inside `Particle`'s code.