# Cant run function (create element) on page load

Tags: javascript, onload, createelement

I use `window.onload()` to create a new div with text inside it. It works if I add it to a button (onclick) but it will not fire when I am using it with `window.onload()`. I have to other `window.onload` in the same js file that works well.. Any idea how I can fix this and what the problem might be?

My code:

```
function addDate() {
    var addDiv = document.createElement('div');
    addDiv.innerHTML = "test";
    document.getElementById('date').appendChild(addDiv);
}
window.onload = addDate();
```

Comment: "I have to other window.onload in the same js file" -- is the other function overwriting this one? You can have only one function assigned to `window.onload`

Comment: I don't feel like writing another answer, but though everyone's right and you can't bind more than one function to onload the way you are,  you're also invoking the function immediately instead of assigning it. `window.onload = addDate` not `addDate()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "I have *to* other window.onload in the same js file" I'm assuming you mean "I have *two* other...", and that would be the problem right there.

If you say:

```
window.onload = doThis;
window.onload = doThat;
```

Only `doThat` gets called. Also, notice... no parentheses! It's `window.onload = doThat`, NOT `window.onload = doThat()`.

If you use:

`window.addEventListener('load', addDate);`

Then you can get the function to be called, and not mess up other functions being called.

Answer (score 3):

1)The way you're binding, you can have just one method attached to an event. You need to add an event listener for what you want.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() { alert("hello!");});
```

Setting directly a method to the onload event will replace any previously attached method. But if you use listeners instead, you can have many of them bound to an event.

2)If you comment out the onload in your external file, when the document.getElementsByClassName("bar") is called, your document isn't ready yet, then, it will return 0 items.

3)Use the addEventListener as I explained in the first point. If you apply this in both places, it will work like a charm.

if you want more info on window.onload check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751362/window-onload-in-external-script-gets-ignored-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a library such as jQuery to do JavaScript work. It's much easier to deal with problems like those. The initialization makes use of the [ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    addDate()
});
```

You can add as many `ready()` calls as you need (one per script).

Under the hood, as mentioned by others, it will use `window.addEventListener(<event name>, <inline function>)`. So we added a little bit of code, things will be a tad bit slower, but you're going to have code that works much faster.

Comment: I'm confused on why you jump to JQuery instead of just adding an event listener?

Comment: `$(document).ready()` is not the same as event as `window.onload`!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, the problem was that I was using window.onload two times in my code. And the solution, as you all said, was to use window.addEventListener instead. I also removed the parantheses.

So for anyone else getting the same problem, use window.addEventListener to trigger the code instead. Like:

```
window.addEventListener('load', databaseToNewElement);
window.addEventListener('load', addDate);
```